# Логическая задача на python с применением if,else,while

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
right_ans = "Куплю."
wrong_ans1 = "Не хочу!"
a1 = "Все так говорят!"
wrong_ans2 = "Зачем?"
a2 = "Все хотят знать!"
a3 = "Хороший ответ!"
congrat = "Ура! С полезной покупкой!"
s = input("Купишь мне слона?")
if s == right_ans:
    print(congrat)
else:
    if s == wrong_ans1:
        print(a1)
    else:
```

Дальше тупняк,я не понимаю почему не работает код после условного оператора else.

Помогите пожалуйста решить!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: во-первых если запустить этот код, то получите `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 1):

```py
guess = ''

while guess != 'Куплю':
    #Python будет входить в блок инструкции while до тех пор, пока пользователь не ответит "Куплю".
    guess = input('Купишь мне слона? ')

    if guess == 'Куплю':
        print('Ура! С полезной покупкой!')
    elif guess == 'Не хочу!':
        print('Все так говорят!\n')
    elif guess == 'Зачем?':
        print('Все хотят знать!\n')
    else:
        print('Хороший ответ.\n')
```

Вывод:

Купишь мне слона? **Нет.**
Хороший ответ.

Купишь мне слона? **Не хочу!**
Все так говорят!

Купишь мне слона? **Зачем?**
Все хотят знать!

Купишь мне слона? **Куплю**
Ура! С полезной покупкой!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
right_ans = "Куплю."
wrong_ans1 = "Не хочу!"
wrong_ans2 = "Зачем?"

a1 = "Все так говорят!"
a2 = "Все хотят знать!"
a3 = "Хороший ответ!"

congrat = "Ура! С полезной покупкой!"

s = input("Купишь мне слона?")
while s!=right_ans:
    if s==wrong_ans1: print(a1)
    elif s==wrong_ans2: print(a2)
    else: print(a3)
    s = input("Купишь мне слона?")
print(congrat)
```